# Missing token - Filtered by token holder?

Tags: tokens, wallets, etherscan

I tried to swap Gfarm2 to Eth, but didnt received my funds, despite it telling me that transaction has been a success. Looking at etherscan it says "FILTERED BY TOKEN HOLDER". what does it mean? could it be the problem of not receiving the funds?

Comment: That just means you were looking at the token transfers for a specific holder I believe. In any case you should look at the specific transaction to see what happened. If you link it here we can help.

Comment: You just made a transfer to another address, no swap. This is the recipient: 0x284DCEA8ECb0fe90EFe07637D3913Ee68B76d8A2.

Comment: Also the other tx is a simple transfer, I'm not sure how you received something back. I can see you made some ETH transfers to the same address 0x284DCEA8ECb0fe90EFe07637D3913Ee68B76d8A2 a while back. If you don't know who it can be, it's possible that your wallet is compromised and someone is draining your tokens/ETH and that is the scammer's wallet.

Comment: Jesus, turns out i entered my metamask wallet, which had almost the same tokens in it as CBW damn. I didnt knew the 12 word phrase works for all the wallets. Its all right now, was all my fault. Thank you so much for being supportive

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone help? My USDT fund is lost.

In my metamask wallet, i saw the fund and in a second it was lost.

I have check in the BscScan the stolen transactions that it was Filtered by Token Holder 0x278e35af0f039477b1187F91374d6B82c3ff7673.

Is there a chance to recover my fund from this holder? or any solution to fix this?
[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92759)